# Mostrar datos JSON mediante un boton

Tags: javascript, json, web

Tengo este codigo que al ejecutar me bota en panatalla los datos, pero en este caso quisiera llamarlo mediante un boton con el evento onClick.

```js
var myEstudiantes ='{"estudiantes":['+
    '{"codigo": "001", "nombre": "Alexandra", "nota": "12"},'+
    '{"codigo": "002", "nombre": "Maria", "nota": 12},'+
    '{"codigo": "003", "nombre": "Juan", "nota": 13},'+
    '{"codigo": "004", "nombre": "Rocio", "nota": 14},'+
    '{"codigo": "005", "nombre": "Rosa", "nota": 2},'+
    '{"codigo": "006", "nombre": "Miguel", "nota": 20},'+
    '{"codigo": "007", "nombre": "Juana", "nota": 10},'+
    '{"codigo": "008", "nombre": "Julio", "nota": 11},'+
    '{"codigo": "009", "nombre": "Alex", "nota": 5},'+
    '{"codigo": "010", "nombre": "Dario", "nota": 13}'+ ']}';

var jsObj = JSON.parse(myEstudiantes);

function leerJSON (json) {
  var out = "===========Estudiantes==========<br>";
  var i;
  
  for(i=0;i<json.estudiantes.length;i++){
    out+="Codigo:"+json.estudiantes[i].codigo+"-"+"Nombre:"+json.estudiantes[i].nombre+"-"+"Codigo:"+json.estudiantes[i].nota+"<br>";
  };
 
  document.getElementById("alumno").innerHTML = out;
  
  //function myFunction(){
  //ocument.getElementById("alumno").innerHTML = out;
  //}
}

leerJSON(jsObj);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <p id="alumno"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var myEstudiantes ='{"estudiantes":['+
'{"codigo": "001", "nombre": "Alexandra", "nota": "12"},'+
'{"codigo": "002", "nombre": "Maria", "nota": 12},'+
'{"codigo": "003", "nombre": "Juan", "nota": 13},'+
'{"codigo": "004", "nombre": "Rocio", "nota": 14},'+
'{"codigo": "005", "nombre": "Rosa", "nota": 2},'+
'{"codigo": "006", "nombre": "Miguel", "nota": 20},'+
'{"codigo": "007", "nombre": "Juana", "nota": 10},'+
'{"codigo": "008", "nombre": "Julio", "nota": 11},'+
'{"codigo": "009", "nombre": "Alex", "nota": 5},'+
'{"codigo": "010", "nombre": "Dario", "nota": 13}'+ ']}';

var jsObj = JSON.parse(myEstudiantes);

function leerJSON (json) {
  var out = "===========Estudiantes==========<br>";
  var i;

  for(i=0;i<json.estudiantes.length;i++){
    out+="Codigo:"+json.estudiantes[i].codigo+"-"+"Nombre:"+json.estudiantes[i].nombre+"-"+"Codigo:"+json.estudiantes[i].nota+"<br>";
  };

  document.getElementById("alumno").innerHTML = out;

}

leerJSON(jsObj);
```

Comment: Obviar etiqueta C

Comment: Simplemente con llamar a `leerJSON(jsObj);`  en tu función `myFunction()` ya te funcionaria. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr de este modo:

Al botón le agregas un `id` por el cual invocarás dicho botón para ejecutar una función por medio del evento `click`

```
<button id="mostrar">Click me</button>
```

Posterior, obtenemos ese botón en JS y le asignamos un handler de este modo

```
mostrar.addEventListener("evento", function(){......})
```

Finalmente el código debería lucir de este modo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="mostrar">Click me</button>
      <p id="alumno"></p>
      
      <script>
    
    
    let mostrar = document.getElementById("mostrar")
    
    mostrar.addEventListener("click", function leerJSON (json) {
          let datos = '{"estudiantes":['+
    '{"codigo": "001", "nombre": "Alexandra", "nota": "12"},'+
    '{"codigo": "002", "nombre": "Maria", "nota": 12},'+
    '{"codigo": "003", "nombre": "Juan", "nota": 13},'+
    '{"codigo": "004", "nombre": "Rocio", "nota": 14},'+
    '{"codigo": "005", "nombre": "Rosa", "nota": 2},'+
    '{"codigo": "006", "nombre": "Miguel", "nota": 20},'+
    '{"codigo": "007", "nombre": "Juana", "nota": 10},'+
    '{"codigo": "008", "nombre": "Julio", "nota": 11},'+
    '{"codigo": "009", "nombre": "Alex", "nota": 5},'+
    '{"codigo": "010", "nombre": "Dario", "nota": 13}'+ ']}';
        
     var json = JSON.parse(datos);
      
      var out = "===========Estudiantes==========<br>";
      var i;
    
      for(i=0;i<json.estudiantes.length;i++){
        out+="Codigo:"+json.estudiantes[i].codigo+"-"+"Nombre:"+json.estudiantes[i].nombre+"-"+"Codigo:"+json.estudiantes[i].nota+"<br>";
      };
    
      document.getElementById("alumno").innerHTML = out;
    
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirve de mucho